# How should I understand "resulting research effort"?

Tags: grammaticality

> Each discipline has contributed techniques and perspectives that are characteristically of its own, and the resulting research effort exhibits an intriguing blend of these different flavors.

In this sentence, "*the resulting research effort*" is to emphasize "result of research effort" or "effort of resulting research"?

Answer (score 1):

The statement given by you apparently describes an interdisciplinary *research **effort***, not the result.

Here the research effort itself is a *result* of blending techniques and perspectives from different disciplines. There is no mention of the *final result* of the research.

**From Cambridge dictionary**:

> [**resulting**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resulting): *adjective* [ before noun ] 
>    caused by the event or situation that you have just
>   mentioned:
>
> The tape was left near a magnetic source, and the *resulting*
>   damage was considerable.